# How to do partial match in full-text search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, typeahead, full-text-indexing

I have a list of places, e.g *"Auckland"*, *"Wellington"*.

My current implementation, won't return these rows if "Auck" or "Welli" is typed.

I am using full-text search, (as there are 30 million rows), and using:

```
CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], 'Auck')
```

This works great, but how can I get it to do partial matches whilst using my full-text index?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following for partial matches on full-text indexed columns.

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE CONTAINS([Field], '"*Auck*"');
```

Same applies for CONTAINSTABLE

```
SELECT * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], '"*Auck*"');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], 'Auckland OR "Auck*"')
```

Comment: Did you include Auck*?

Comment: @TavoloPerUno,  Why we need 'Auckland OR "Auck*"', if we only type '"Auck*"' ?